# Finding gaps in server data using presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have the data for requests sent to a server with the API endpoint name and the epoch at which the request was sent. There are many API endpoints (in thousands). There was an issue due to which the requests didn't come into the server. I want to find out the list of APIs whose data didn't come in, i.e., I want to find out the gaps in this server data.

I followed some examples in https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-series-of-events-in-sql/. But this uses window functions and works well for consecutive dates for a single group but doesn't extend to multiple groups of epochs since they might not be consecutive. I want to extend this to my use case, where there are multiple APIs, each with its own epochs and gaps. How can I do it in Presto?

Example schema in the table

```
endpointid (string)
serverepoch (integer)
```

Example Data

```
endpointid1, 123
endpointid2, 123
endpointid1, 234
endpointid2, 567
```

From this data, say I want to find all gaps of 300 seconds or more then I get

```
endpointid2 123
endpointid2 567
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the lead and lag functions as the following:

```
with next_prev_serverepoch_gaps as
(
  select *,
    case 
     when lead(serverepoch, 1, serverepoch) over (partition by endpointid order by serverepoch) - serverepoch >= 300
       or serverepoch - lag(serverepoch, 1, serverepoch) over (partition by endpointid order by serverepoch) >= 300
     then 1 else 0
    end as gap_flag
  from table_name
)
select endpointid, serverepoch
from next_prev_serverepoch_gaps
where gap_flag = 1
order by endpointid, serverepoch
```